# Is there a way to search for questions with a specific deleted tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

When a tag has been deleted from questions, those questions won't show up in a search for the tag.  However, the deleted tag still shows in the edit history of those questions.  Is there a way to include edit history in a search for questions that previously had a specific tag?

Comment: This would be possible for smaller tags using SEDE, or if you have other criteria that would limit the number of records (e.g., questions from a specific user). If you want to find (or search in) all questions that ever showed any given tag, I'm not aware of a way that would help with that.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, thanks. My own application would primarily be on a small site with <2100 questions. I assume any search would need to look at all questions to see if they fit, but our most popular tag has <200 questions, so any deleted tag would have far fewer. So if I learn how to program SEDE, I'll be in business?

Comment: By "deleted from questions", do you mean any given tag that is simply edited out of some question or do you mean tags that were actually deleted from the system (i.e., burninated)?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, I can use either case on various occasions, but the current need that triggered the question was tags deleted from the system. My recollection is that even burninated tags show in the edit history. But of course there would be no way to search for those as tags if the tags no longer exist. I was thinking there might be a way to search on the text of the tag, possibly including whatever internal markup distinguishes the text as a tag for display formatting purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1673844/find-questions-that-previously-used-a-specific-burninated-tag?TagName=workflow) that will return questions that previously used a specific burninated tag:

```sql
DECLARE @TagName AS VARCHAR(35) = '##TagName##'

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tags WHERE TagName = @TagName) = 0
  SELECT DISTINCT ph.PostId AS [Post Link]
  FROM PostHistory ph
  WHERE ph.PostHistoryTypeId IN (3, 6) --(Initial Tags, Edit Tags)
  AND ph.TEXT LIKE '%<' + @TagName + '>%'
ELSE
  PRINT 'Tag exists in the system.'
```

You may type your desired site name in the "Switch site" field to test on a different site.